# How does list comprehension with an `if` clause work?

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, mode

How does the `max_list` variable list comprehension work?

```
def mode(*args):
    dict_vals = {i: args.count(i) for i in args}
    max_list = [k for k, v in dict_vals.items() if v == max(dict_vals.values())]
    return max_list
```

I know that the `dict_vals` creates a dictionary that holds onto the values you enter (the key) and the number of occurrences for each value (the value of the key). I also know that `max_list` creates a list of the keys (values) that occur the most based on the being the maximum value (occurrence).
I am just wanting to know how the comprehension used in `max_list` works and maybe some other examples of turning dictionaries into lists with similar syntax for useful applications. Also, is there similar ways to do this with tuples?

Comment: As an aside, this is an anti-pattern: `{i: args.count(i) for i in args}`. It is unecessarily inefficient, it is quadratic time and can trivially be achieved in linear time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict_vals.items()
```

The `items()` method yields each key-value pair in the dictionary.

```
k, v in dict_vals.items()
```

This iterates over each key-value pair in the dictionary yielded by `items()`

```
k, v in dict_vals.items() if v == max(dict_vals.values())
```

This filters that list of key-value pairs by selecting only those pairs where the value is equal to maximum in value stored in the `dict_vals` (`.values()` gives you all the values & `max()` finds the largest among those).

Finally,

```
k for k,v in dict_vals.items() if v == max(dict_vals.values())
```

Selects only the key (`k`) for those pairs. The `[]` makes it a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
max_list = [k for k, v in dict_vals.items() if v == max(dict_vals.values())]
```

Does something similar to:

```
max_list = []
for k,v in dict_vals.items():
    if v == max(dict_vals.values()):
        max_list.append(k)
```

The first variable in the list comprehension (in this case `k`) is always what's going to be in the list. The conditional at the end checks whether the current item in the loop should be added. If you want the result in a tuple I believe you just wrap the outside in a tuple (a simple parentheses won't do since the interpreter might think you're just grouping the operation).

```
max_list = tuple(k for k, v in dict_vals.items() if v == max(dict_vals.values()))
```